# Chilkat CkHttpResponse header() Method is Buggy

Tags: c++, chilkat

Assume the following HTTP response with the **Date** header (could be any other header) **starting with a space**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
 Date: Sun, 29 Feb 2010 15:14:06 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Querying a server with such a response using the following Chilkat code snippet,

```
// other stuff
CkHttpResponse* resp;
// other stuff
std::cout << resp->header();
```

yields this result:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 Date: Sun, 29 Feb 2010 15:14:06 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The header() parser is appending the **Date** header to the value of the previous header, and in this case, the **Server** header.

And if the **Date** header happens to be the first in the list of headers, then the header() parser trims the leading space.

Note: I've tested it with the latest version, v9.5.0.97.

Comment: I think the RFC doesn't allow an HTTP header to start with a whitespace, because this is used as an indication of a continuation (i.e., a header spanning multiple lines), see [4.2 Message Headers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.2). So, it seems that Chilkat is behaving correctly, and whoever sends that bogus Date header (Microsoft IIS, or perhaps some server-side script) is violating the specs.